# ttk Entry widget ignores font applied via style?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Style, Entry
import tkinter.font as tkfont

root = Tk()

font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=30, slant='italic')
style = Style()
style.configure('Custom.TEntry', font=font, foreground='green')
entry_font = Entry(root, font=font, foreground='green')
entry_font.insert(0, 'directly configured')
entry_font.pack()
entry_style = Entry(root, style='Custom.TEntry')
entry_style.insert(0, 'styled entry')
entry_style.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The first entry responds to the font whereas the second does not.
Is there a way to apply the font using styles?

Answer (score 3):

from: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Entry.html

> Use this option to specify the font of the text that will appear in
>   the widget; see Section 5.4, “Type fonts”. For reasons that are
>   unclear to the author, this option cannot be specified with a style.

guess i'll do it directly

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds.

You can add semi-direct `font=style.lookup("Custom.TEntry", "font")` to your `Entry`. It is not pretty but you can still have styles in one place.

```py
from tkinter.ttk import Style, Entry

style = Style()
style.configure('Custom.TEntry', font=('sans-serif', 30), foreground='green')

# somewhere else in the code
style = Style()
entry = Entry(root, style="Custom.TEntry", font=style.lookup("Custom.TEntry", "font"))
```

You can also subclass original `Entry` and fix it.

```py
from tkinter.ttk import Style, Entry

class StyledEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, widget=None, **kw):
        if "font" not in kw:
            style = kw.get("style", "TEntry")
            kw["font"] = Style().lookup(style, "font")

        super().__init__(master=master, widget=widget, **kw)

# and later just
entry = StyledEntry(root, style="Custom.TEntry")
```

Comment: this solution unfortunately only clears up a little, but in the end does not solve the underlying issue where applying different style will have no effect on given Entry(also Combobox from my experience) instance, and for them special handling is required to change font

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you can configure the font in the tk manner:

```
entry_font.configure(font=('TkTextFont', 20))
```

Comment: The OP is already doing that for the first part of the code. The question is about how to do it the other way, using styles.

Comment: Then the answer is 'no', but the method for configuring the font remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

> The first entry responds to the font whereas the second does not. Is
> there a way to apply the font using styles?

The problem can be fixed.

- Add `ttk.` prefix for `Entry` widgets.
- Add `style='Custom.TEntry'` for `Entry` widgets parameter.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Style, Entry
import tkinter.font as tkfont


root = tk.Tk()

font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=30, slant='italic')
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Custom.TEntry', foreground='green') 

entry_font = ttk.Entry(root,
                       style='Custom.TEntry',
                       font=font)
entry_font.insert(0, 'directly configured' )
 
entry_style = ttk.Entry(root,
                        style='Custom.TEntry',
                        font=font)

entry_style.insert(0, 'styled entry')

entry_font.pack()
entry_style.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]